# How did Rohan get enrolled to Engineering college?

Tags: udaan

I was watching [*Udaan* (2010)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udaan_(2010_film)). In the movie the protagonist Rohan gets expelled from college in 12th standard (mentioned on his suitcase). How did he then join engineering in Jamshedpur despite not completing 12th?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a long time and it does seem like a plot hole since eligibility for engineering is indeed 12th pass.

But there is another way to engineering college which does not passes through 12th grade.

One can opt for **[Diploma in Engineering after 10th grade](http://www.indiaeducation.net/engineering/engineering-degrees/diploma-in-engineering.html)**, which is of 3 years and after completing it one can get a direct admission to 2nd year of engineering. I have a friend who did the same.

So I think he was enrolled in Diploma and not Bachelors of Engineering.

Comment: @piechuckerr: 100 times !! That movie must have made some impression on you.